# Prevent adding first line when using htmlParse() from 'XML' package

Tags: html, xml, r, xml-parsing

I have a problem while doing a `htmlParse()` on a XHTML document.

When it loads into R as an 'externalptr', I can see that one line is added, at the top of the file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
```

I don't want to make this line appear because it breaks my application. I would like to delete it within the `htmlParse()` function, and not having to delete this line manually for each XHTML I have.

Any suggestions? I've tried changing some parameters passed to the function `htmlParse()` but at this time, after trying with it, I have not found it.

If it helps, here are the first lines of the XHTML I parse:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<html dir="ltr" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:epub="http://www.idpf.org/2007/ops" xml:lang="es">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
```

Comment: Do you need the `<?xml version ...>` line?  If not, use `xmlRoot(doc)`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But it also breaks it. It is a file extracted from an epub, and if I delete that line, it can't load within my iPad's iBooks. Haven't tried for other platforms like Android.

Comment: We could really use some more code & data to help. How are you extracting the resultant HTML? If it's with `saveXML`, why not just use `gsub` to replace the first line (though `saveXML` by default should put the `<xml…`  prefix.

Comment: Thank you all. Finally you both helped me to discover the solution. I tried with `xmlRoot()` and then saved with `saveXML()` with that prefix, and the last problem that appeared was an encoding error, because I was using cyrillic letters mixed with latin letters. Tried under Windows to change encondings but no success. Finally under Linux worked.

Comment: Cool. You should add what you did as an answer. It'll help others and you can accept the answer in a couple days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried with `xmlRoot()` and then saved with `saveXML()`, including as parameters the prefix `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>`

There was also an encoding problem but that's another story. In Windows didn't work, in Ubuntu finally worked.

Thank you all.